# How to groupby for dataframe which has a datetimeindex only using hours

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, pandas-groupby

I've got a dataframe called new_dh of web request that looks like (there are more columns

```
                    s-sitename     sc-win32-status
date_time                                                           
2006-11-01 00:00:00     W3SVC1          0.0
2006-11-01 00:00:00     W3SVC1          0.0
2006-11-01 01:00:00     W3SVC1          0.0
2006-11-01 01:00:00     W3SVC1          0.0
2006-11-01 02:00:00     W3SVC1          0.0
2007-02-28 02:00:00     W3SVC1          0.0
2007-02-28 10:00:00     W3SVC1          0.0
2007-02-28 23:00:00     W3SVC1          0.0
2007-02-28 23:00:00     W3SVC1          0.0
2007-02-28 23:00:00     W3SVC1          0.0
```

What I would like to do is group by the hours(the actual date of the request does not matter, just the hour and all the times have already been rounded down to not include minutes) for the datetimeindex and instead return

```
                    count 
hour                                                           
0                    2
01                   2
02                   2
10                   1
23                   3
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

I have tried

```
new_dh.groupby([new_dh.index.hour]).count()
```

but find myself printing many columns of the same value whereas I only want the above version

Answer (score 3):

If need `DatetimeIndex` in output use [`DataFrame.resample`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html):

```
new_dh.resample('H')['s-sitename'].count()
```

Or [`DatetimeIndex.floor`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DatetimeIndex.floor.html):

```
new_dh.groupby(new_dh.index.floor('H'))['s-sitename'].count()
```

Problem of your solution is if use [`GroupBy.count`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.count.html) it count all columns value per `Hour`s with exclude missing values, so if no missing values get multiple columns with same values. Possible solution is specify column after `groupby`:

```
new_dh.groupby([new_dh.index.hour])['s-sitename'].count()
```

So data was changed for see how count with exclude missing values:

```
print (new_dh)
                    s-sitename  sc-win32-status
date_time                                      
2006-11-01 00:00:00     W3SVC1              0.0
2006-11-01 00:00:00     W3SVC1              0.0
2006-11-01 01:00:00     W3SVC1              0.0
2006-11-01 01:00:00     W3SVC1              0.0
2006-11-01 02:00:00        NaN              0.0
2007-02-28 02:00:00     W3SVC1              0.0
2007-02-28 10:00:00     W3SVC1              0.0
2007-02-28 23:00:00        NaN              0.0
2007-02-28 23:00:00        NaN              0.0
2007-02-28 23:00:00     W3SVC1              0.0


df = new_dh.groupby([new_dh.index.hour]).count()

print (df)
           s-sitename  sc-win32-status
date_time                             
0                   2                2
1                   2                2
2                   1                2
10                  1                1
23                  1                3
```

So if column is specified:

```
s = new_dh.groupby([new_dh.index.hour])['s-sitename'].count()
print (s)
date_time
0     2
1     2
2     1
10    1
23    1
Name: s-sitename, dtype: int64

df = new_dh.groupby([new_dh.index.hour])['s-sitename'].count().to_frame()

print (df)
           s-sitename
date_time            
0                   2
1                   2
2                   1
10                  1
23                  1
```

If need count also missing values then use [`GroupBy.size`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.size.html):

```
s = new_dh.groupby([new_dh.index.hour])['s-sitename'].size()
print (s)
date_time
0     2
1     2
2     2
10    1
23    3
Name: s-sitename, dtype: int64

df = new_dh.groupby([new_dh.index.hour])['s-sitename'].size().to_frame()

print (df)
           s-sitename
date_time            
0                   2
1                   2
2                   2
10                  1
23                  3
```

Answer (score 1):

```py
new_dh['hour'] = new_dh.index.map(lambda x: x.hour)
new_dh.groupby('hour')['hour'].count()
```

Result

```sh
hour
0     2
1     2
2     2
10    1
23    3
Name: hour, dtype: int64
```

If you need a DataFrame as result:

```py
new_dh.groupby('hour')['hour'].count().rename('count').to_frame()
```

In this case, the result will be:

```sh
      count
hour       
0         2
1         2
2         2
10        1
23        3
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this by using `groupby()` and `assign()` method:

If 'date_time' column is not your index:

```
result=df.assign(hour=df['date_time'].dt.hour).groupby('hour').agg(count=('s-sitename','count'))
```

If It's your index then use:

```
result=df.groupby(df.index.hour)['s-sitename'].count().to_frame('count')
result.index.name='hour'
```

Now if you print `result` then you will get your desired output:

```
      count
hour    
0       1
1       2
2       2
10      1
23      3
```